# Views Contextual filter using two terms, one assigned to node and one not

Tags: views

I have a view which uses TID from a single vocabulary as a contextual filter to create a dynamic slideshow.

This slideshow is displayed on nodes of a specific content type ("Landing Page"). The images for the slideshow are loaded from another content type ("Slideshow"). Both are tagged with terms from a common vocabulary with only one level.

The slideshow then displays all images tagged with the same term as the current landing page. This bit is working as intended.

However, I also want all slideshows to include images tagged with another term from the same vocabulary. This term has not been assigned to the landing page.

So, I'm looking for a way to achieve something like this:

Show all images tagged with the TID from the current node AND all images tagged with term 58.

Term 58 is static and will not change.

I've tried all manner of configurations with no luck. I figure I could use some PHP code in the contextual filter but haven't been able to find anything similar that would help. Worse case scenario is I create a separate display in the view for each term but that just seems inefficient.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

You can use relationship settings to add in the taxonomy, and then add field to also add items tagged with that Term into the slideshow.

Something like this:

Edit your view and add a relationship (3rd column on right) for
Content: Taxonomy terms on node

Then under your filters add:

"Taxonomy term: Term" and Select the term that is 58

I just did a test with a sample view and results were as expected, it showed me all the items for that node plus the specific term.